# Mysql query to get parent details in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where i store categories with its parent's id. Following is the table structure
What i need is to get the parent and details of id 4 in a single query without php recursion

```
id | CategoryName | parentid
1      Web            0
2      Software       0
3      PHP            1
4      Arrays         3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL: Retrieve a single path in the Adjacency List model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627878/php-mysql-retrieve-a-single-path-in-the-adjacency-list-model)

Comment: Do you mean to say you want to retrieve the full chain of inheritance? `child -> parent -> parent -> parent -> ... 0`?  Cannot be done without recursion.

Comment: ya that was what i was looking for.. thanks michael..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A self join should be sufficient here.  Your goal is to join the table against itself, while relating the `parentid` of the main row to the `id` of its parent's row.

```sql
SELECT 
  me.id AS me_id,
  me.CategoryName AS me_category,
  parent.id AS parent_id,
  parent.CategoryName AS parent_category
FROM
  tablename me JOIN tablename parent ON me.parentid = parent.id
WHERE me.id = 4
```

Comment: thanks for the reply michael but the problem . this categories can have any number of levels .According to your query i get only 2 levels

Comment: @Anish Joseph You need to explain what you mean by _any number of levels_.  The example table in your question does not illustrate that.  You show a 1:1 relationship from child to parent.

Answer (score 0):

Would a variation of

```
select * from categories t1 join categories t2 where t1.parentid=t2.id
```

work for you

Comment: No, all the data is in the same table, there is no `t1` or `t2`

Comment: @Rikudo Sennin t1 and t2 are aliases, it's self join.